# select the value from a checkbox in wpf data grid

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to select the value from the datagrid checkbox (whether it is checked or unchecked) and second column(UserName). Here is the datagrid code.

```
     <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"  Name="enableDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="0,0,0,81">
     <DataGrid.Columns>
     <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>                                           
             <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>                                      
          </DataTemplate>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn>
     <DataGridTextColumn Header="User Name" Binding="{Binding Path=uName}"/>
     </DataGrid.Column>
     </DataGrid>
```

How should i achieve it ?Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the checkbox to a property in your itemsource then you can get the selected row from the datagrid

```
<CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding myBool}"/>  

MyDatagridItem item = MyDatagrid.SelectedItem as MyDatagridItem

if(item.myBool == true){
...
}
```

Comment: Hi Jim,
What is MyDatagridItem  here ??

Comment: The class that is holding the datagrid data. In your original post you bind uName. What class holds uName?

Answer (score 1):

Use `DataGridCheckBoxColumn` instead:

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding IsChecked}" />
```